# Can't map Bug work item "New" state to "New" on the Kanban board

Tags: tfs

We have recently upgraded TFS from 2012 to 2013, and are starting to look at using the Kanban board.

We encountered a slight problem because the Bug work item type in the "MSF for Agile Software Development" process template does not have a "New" state. This meant that when choosing to hide "In progress" items items on the backlog, the bugs weren't shown.

To remedy that, we manually added a "New" state to the Bug template, and added two transitions between it and "Active". All our backlogged bugs were then set to "New". So far so good.

The problem now is that the New column on the Kanban board won't allow us to map to the newly added state:

[image]

The combo box is just disabled. Is there a way that we can edit the board so that the metastate of "New" can be properly associated with the work item state of "New" for the Bug work item type here?

**Edit**: As per ds19's comment below, yes - I have looked at the processconfiguration.xml file, and have these states defined for the `Microsoft.BugCategory`;

```
<States>
  <State type="Proposed" value="New" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
  <State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
  <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
</States>
```

Comment: Did you check the ProcessConfiguration.xml file? See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh500408.aspx

Comment: @ds19 yeah, take a look at my edit - I went in there and added the Proposed <--> New mapping after creating the new state.

Comment: Did you check the Transitions for Bug?  I think it has to do with the transition from null: <transition from="" to="New">  
from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194981.aspx
"Use the TRANSITION element to define a transition for each valid progression and regression from one state to another.
At a minimum, you must define one transition for each state, and the transition from the null state to the initial state.
You can define only one transition from unassigned (null) to the initial state. When you save a new work item, it is automatically assigned to the initial state."